# Seleniumで取得保存したファイル名の特定

Tags: python, ubuntu, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Ubuntu＋Python＋SeleniumでChromeを自動化し、Saveボタンをクリックしてファイルをローカルに保存するところまで出来ましたが、このファイル名が手動で制御出来ず、取得元のサイトが検索ワードに基づいて付けた適当な名前になります。
この、たった今保存されたファイルのファイル名をPythonで取得する場合、どの方法が賢いでしょうか。
ディレクトリを検索し、正規表現でファイル名に合致したリストを得て、最も新しいものがそれだ、というのを考えましたが、たぶんあるあるの事例だと思いますので、より良い方法がありましたらご教示くだされば幸いです。

Comment: Chrome依存で対象ファイルが一つだけなら専用の一時ダウンロードフォルダを作成して指定するやり方があるようです。記事はWindows環境のようですが。[Python Selenium 動的なダウンロード完了待機](https://qiita.com/hajimejimejime/items/58949dc18b52ae926b1b)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
*.crdownloadたしかに出来ます！
ダウンロードが終わったかの監視も分からなくてなんとなく30秒待っていたので超助かります！
Ubuntuに移植して動作するか確認します。

Comment: ファイル名が (web サイト側で) 毎回任意の名前で決められている、ということでしょうか？差し支えない範囲で再現できる実際のコードも質問中に含まれていると、具体的なアドバイスが付けやすくなると思います。

Comment: おっしゃる通りです。保存ボタンしかなく、ファイル名を入力したり、ファイル位置を指定するダイアログボックスが出ず、いきなり決め打ちの名前で指定場所（Seleniumの場合は作業ディレクトリ）に出来てしまうんです。kunifさんのくださったヒントで問題を解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

> Ubuntu＋Python＋Selenium

ご質問の前提条件から外れてしまいますが、 Selenium ではなく [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) であれば、直接ダウンロードするパスとファイル名を指定する方法があります。
→ [puppeteer でファイルをダウンロードするときに、任意のパスと名前で保存する | Aqua Ware つぶやきブログ](https://aquasoftware.net/blog/?p=1583)

上記の記事は、 node.js + Puppeteer の例ですが、 [pyppeteer](https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer) を使うことで、以下のように Python でも同様の結果が得られます。

```py
import os
import asyncio

# Fetch.enable に対応している Chromeimum リビジョンを指定
os.environ['PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION'] = '884014'
import pyppeteer

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

async def main(file_name, headless=True, wait_time=5.0):
    b = await pyppeteer.launch({'headless': headless})
    p = await b.newPage()
    await p.goto('https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer')
    e = await p.querySelector('get-repo')
    await e.click()

    client = await p.target.createCDPSession()
    await client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', { 'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': os.getcwd() })
    await client.send('Fetch.enable', { 'patterns': [ { 'urlPattern': '*', 'requestStage': 'Response' }] })

    async def onRequestPaused(requestEvent):
        responseHeaders = [v for v in requestEvent['responseHeaders'] if v['name'] != 'content-disposition']
        requestId = requestEvent['requestId']
        if requestEvent['responseStatusCode'] == 200:
            responseHeaders.append({ 'name': 'content-disposition', 'value': f'attachment; filename="{file_name}"'})
            response = await client.send('Fetch.getResponseBody', { 'requestId': requestId })
            await client.send('Fetch.fulfillRequest', { 'requestId': requestId, 'responseCode': 200, 'responseHeaders': responseHeaders, 'body': response['body'] })
        else:
            await client.send('Fetch.continueRequest', { 'requestId': requestId }); 
    client.on('Fetch.requestPaused', lambda e: asyncio.ensure_future(onRequestPaused(e), loop=event_loop))

    # Github の "Download ZIP" のボタンをクリック
    e = await p.querySelector('a[href$=".zip"]')
    await e.click()
    await asyncio.sleep(wait_time)
    await client.send('Fetch.disable')
    await b.close()

event_loop.run_until_complete(main(file_name='specified_name.zip', headless=False))
```

Windows および WSL 上の Ubuntu で動作確認済みです。

pyppeteer のオリジナルが node.js であることから、基本非同期な API となっているため、 Selenium の同期的な API に慣れていると、扱いづらいとは思います。
参考になれば。

Comment: ここ 2～3年ほど α版, β版が続いている Selenium 4 であれば、 Puppeteer と同様 WebDriver が不要になり、  Chrome DevTools Protocol や Remote Debugging Protocol へのアクセスがフルサポートされます。このため、同等の操作ができるようになりそうですが、正式リリース前でドキュメントが揃っていないのもあって、イベントハンドラを登録する方法がパッと見つかりませんでした。もしかしたら Selenium 4 ならできるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
なんとなくSeleniumをバッドハックして出来てしまいましたので、今回はこのまま進みますが、今回問題があれば、あるいは将来的にpyppeteerやSelenium 4を使うことも検討します。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

コメントでお示しいただいた、以下の記事を参考に解決しました。

[Python Selenium 動的なダウンロード完了待機](https://qiita.com/hajimejimejime/items/58949dc18b52ae926b1b)

実は表題の問題の他に、ダウンロードの終了を関知できないという問題もあったのですが、同時に解決してハッピーです。
拙ソースを掲げます。

守秘義務の関係でぼかしていますが、以下の条件とします。

- `https://foo.example.com/` というサイトを検索する
- barbarbar、bazbazbazというワードで検索する
- 検索結果はfoo_search_*.txtという名前で保存される（*の部分はbarbarb~1のような、検索ワードを元にした短縮した名前になるようだ？）

プログラムの要点は以下の通りです。

- glob.glob関数を使って、foo_search_*.txt.crdownloadというファイルがあるかぎり、１秒待ちながらループする
- ループの中で、foo_search_*.txt.crdownloadから.crdownloadを削除してファイル名を得る
- ループを脱出した場合は、ダウンロードが終わったか、そもそもダウンロードが行えなかったかであるので、適当に処理する

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import glob 
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By # for find_element_by_ID
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # wait.untilの秒数の上限
driver.get('https://foo.example.com/') # 検索サイト
print(driver.title)

def search_and_save(search_term):
    element = 
    wait.until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_term_id"))) # 検索ボックスが表示されるのを待つ
    element.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
    element.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    element.send_keys(search_term) # 検索ワードを入力してサブミット
    element.submit()
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("search-submit").click()
    new_file = 'ERROR' + search_term # ダウンロードするファイル名、最初はエラー名にしておく
    for i in range(30): # MAX30秒待つ
        download_fileName = glob.glob(f'foo_search_*.txt.crdownload') # crdownloadを探す
        if download_fileName: # crdownloadがあれば
            new_file = download_fileName[0].replace('.crdownload', '') # crdownloadを削除したものでnew_fileを置き換える
            time.sleep(1) # 1秒待つ
        else: # crdownloadがない。downloadが終わったかそもそも始まってなかった
            break
       print('new_file:' + new_file) # ダウンロードが正常に終わっていればそのファイル名が、ダウンロードされていなければファイル名が入る

search_and_save('barbarbar')
search_and_save('bazbazbaz')
driver.quit()
```